# Nightmare with Mocha: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, nightmare

I'm trying to run an example test with Nightmare.js and Mocha, and I keep getting the error above. Here is the full output:

```
$ mocha nightmare-chai-example.js 


  Nightmare demo
    Start page
      1) should show form when loaded


  0 passing (716ms)
  1 failing

  1) Nightmare demo Start page should show form when loaded:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
      at Nightmare.done (/home/user/testing/node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js:313:14)
      at Nightmare.next (/home/user/testing/node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js:291:35)
      at /home/user/testing/node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js:301:46
      at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/user/testing/node_modules/nightmare/lib/ipc.js:93:18)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/user/testing/node_modules/nightmare/lib/ipc.js:49:10)
      at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:695:10)
      at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:440:11)
```

And here is the code that I'm running:

```
var path = require('path');
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var should = require('chai').should();

describe('Nightmare demo', function() {
  this.timeout(15000); // Set timeout to 15 seconds

  var url = 'http://example.com';

  describe('Start page', function() {
    it('should show form when loaded', function(done) {
      new Nightmare()
        .goto(url)
        .evaluate(function() {
          return document.querySelectorAll('form').length;
        }, function(result) {
          result.should.equal(1);
          done();
        })
        .run();
    });
  });
});
```

From [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MikaelSoderstrom/4842a97ec399aae1e024).

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.run()` expects a callback and will fail (with unhelpful output, as you have noticed) without it.  This has been [reported](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/500) and a [fix has been proposed](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/501).

It's also probably worth pointing out that `.evaluate()` does not work the way the gist you supplied describes, at least for versions >2.x.  The `.evaluate()` method will try to send arguments after the evaluated function (the first argument) as arguments to that function.

Modifying the inside of your `it` call:

```
  new Nightmare()
    .goto(url)
    .evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelectorAll('form').length;
    })
    .run(function(err, result){
      result.should.equal(1);
      done();
    });
```

It's *also* worth pointing out that `.run()` is for internal use, and it's been suggested for [deprecation](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/575) in favor of the Promise-like implementation using `.then()`:

```
  new Nightmare()
    .goto(url)
    .evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelectorAll('form').length;
    })
    .then(function(result){
      result.should.equal(1);
      done();
    });
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a ton! However, when I changed my code to use .then, it timed out every time. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: Hm, not offhand.  This conversation may be better suited for [gitter](https://gitter.im/rosshinkley/nightmare) and posting here when a solution is found.